# how to select values based on conditions from multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which contains information about road traffic accidents (below)

[image]

i'm able to extract the information from the various columns as i want - [image]

But am having trouble extracting information based on conditionals from two columns -

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve here is to extract the ages of all casualties based on 'Dry' road conditions, but only have the ages displayed not the weather conditions, if that makes sense?

any help would be appreciated !

thanks

Comment: Your condition is not clear. can you say in words what your condition is? ad show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
surface.loc[surface['Road Surface] == 'Dry','Age of Casualty']
```